# Is there a way to load files simultaneously in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I have a problem with regard to loading some files in Ruby. They are set up like so:

```
.
├── file1.rb
├── file2.rb
└── load_files.rb
```

`file1.rb`

```
class File1
  # contains a reference to the File2 class
end
```

`file2.rb`

```
class File2
  # contains a reference to the File1 class
end
```

`load_files.rb`

```
require './file1'
require './file2'
```

The problem here is that both classes make references to each other, but `File1` gets loaded before `File2` so it crashes because `File2` is not yet defined. The same problem will occur if you reverse the order of the loading of the files, so that's out of the question. The only way that I can see to resolve this issue is to load `file1.rb` and `file2.rb` simultaneously, but  I don't know if this is possible. Does anyone see a way to resolve this by either loading the files simultaneously or by some other means?

Comment: Restructure your code so this problem doesn't occur - if you reduce your code to a minimal example that exhibits the problem then someone can give a concrete answer

Comment: You should only be getting an error if both files contain code which is run at load time (like in a class body or at the top level). The simplest solution is to wrap the references in methods, which you only call once both files are loaded.